# Short story about an elite that has mentally regressed due to assistive AI technologies

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I came upon a comment describing a scifi short story where reliance on technology meant to improve appearance and demeanor has led to mental regression and AI control of the upper class that employs it. Unfortunately, I only have the following description to go on:

> I'm reminded of a Nebula(?) Award winning short story about hive-rats 
>   interacting with nobility in the 'future'. The nobility is shrouded in apperance/voice/stim tech such that the AIs are more the person than anything. A princess is brought to the under-city by her father to a shop that can fix the princess' tech, as it is malfunctioning. The daughter of the shop owner tries to peer into the princess' life and psyche as the shop owner tries to fix the princess. The princess has implants that stimulate her face, voice, and body to say the right things at the right times, to move the right way, that changes her face via lightsheets to be most beautiful to the observer she is with, that causes her to say just the right thing at just the right time and be increbily witty. But the daughter of the shop owner tries to peer through the tech to see the woman behind the veil. She discovers that the person behind it all is nearly mute and has the intelligence of an infant. The tech had been installed before ego formation and the person behind it all didn't really exist. She discovers it is also true of the man that brought the princess down to them too. The entire nobility is essentially faking it.

Comment: [Presumably this is the original source](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=20567123) - about a fifth of the way down the thread.

Comment: That's the one, but [here's](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=20569666) a link to the comment directly. I wasn't sure if I could use links on a brand new account.

Comment: I've taken a look at the nebula winning list, but haven't seen nothing about it :(

Comment: You've rekindled a memory - I have definitely read this story! But I can't for the life of me remember the name nor author. I hope you find the answer. I'll have to look through my past readings, but unfortunately I'm better at remembering novels than short stories . . .

Comment: "The Girl-Thing who went out for Sushi"? Pat Cadigan, won the Hugo award for best novelette in 2013. Doesn't match all the details perfectly though.